# search for pattern in string

Tags: python, search

I need to find a pattern ATG[any number of any characters triplets][TGA or TAG or TGA], where I need only the first ATG, further up to [TGA or TAG or TAA] do not matter.

And this should be interrupted at [TGA or TAG or TAA]. 
In string there could be several such, they do not need to overlap.

For example search on 'ATGcccATGgggTAGgATGtttTAA' should give 'ATGcccATGgggTAG' and 'ATGtttTAA' as a result.

Is there any way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for a regex. (Note that your expected result does not seem to match your specification; you originally say you want to match up to TGA, TAG or TGA, but then in the result you match up to TAA. I'll assume the end of the string is meant to be TGA.)

```
import re
target = 'ATGcccATGgggTAGgATGtttTGA'
results = re.findall(r'(ATG.*?(?:TAG|TGA|TGA))', target)
# ['ATGcccATGgggTAG', 'ATGtttTGA']
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake. I was to tell that matching pattern should end [TGA or TAG or TAA]. With replacing one of TGA in your regular expression with TAA it works as desired!  
Thank you very much. This is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a pro, so there might be nicer and/or more effective solutions, but this does the trick:

```
s = 'ATGcccATGgggTAGgATGtttTAA'
start = 'ATG'
stop = ['TGA', 'TAG', 'TGA', 'TAA', 'TGG']
temp = ''
results = []
i = 0
while i < len(s):
    if s[i].isupper():
        temp = s[i:i+3]
        if temp == start:
            for j in range(3,len(s)-i):
                if s[i+j].isupper():
                    temp = s[i+j:i+j+3]
                    if temp in stop:
                        temp = s[i:i+j+3]
                        i += j+3
                        results.append(temp)
                        break
    else:
        i += 1
print results
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a possible way, but would it work if all letters are uppercase?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. I thought that those filler characters are always lower case, it would need some changes. But you already have a very nice solution, so...